# Remember-me service is not working when I store the token in the database

Tags: spring, spring-security, token, persistent, remember-me

After setting up spring security remember me (Persistent Token approach), the data of the user is stored into the database ('persistent_token' table). And I can see 'SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE' in my browser. When I delete 'JSESSIONID' from my browser to check whether works the remember-me service, I get to the login page.

My config looks like this:

```
http
   .rememberMe()
     .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices("myAppKey"));

@Bean
     public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices(String internalSecretKey) {
         BasicRememberMeUserDetailsService rememberMeUserDetailsService = new BasicRememberMeUserDetailsService();
//       InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl rememberMeTokenRepository = new InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl();
         JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
         db.setDataSource(dataSource);
         db.setCreateTableOnStartup(false);
         PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices services = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(internalSecretKey, rememberMeUserDetailsService, db);
         services.setAlwaysRemember(true);
         services.setUseSecureCookie(true);
         return services;
     }
```

The remember-me service works well with "in-memory" storage, when I store the tokens in the memory.

I've created the "persistent_logins" table as well. When I login first time in my application, then the token get stored in the database properly, but when I want to login with the remember-me service, the token does not get read from the database. Also the `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` is not used as well. It does not read out the token from the database.

Does anybody have any idea why?

Thanks your help in advance!

**UPDATE:**

After several experiment I've figured out that the following line cause this:

```
services.setUseSecureCookie(true);
```

Does anybody have idea why? Or can somebody explain what does this config do?